# Django Admin actions don't work after redefining primary key of the model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, primary-key, django-admin-actions

I am using standard models.Model in Django. I changed my primary key to _id (mongo). After that, actions in Django Admin don't work anymore. For example, when I use the default Django action – Delete selected, no object is found through the query. However, no problem occurs when I edit or delete objects manually. Is there any way to fix it?

[Are you sure you want to delete the selected companies? -> Summary, objects: None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdqdq.png)

Comment: Did you migrate your changes?

Comment: @JSRB yes I did.

Comment: Try re-creating all migrations and database.

Answer (score 0):

```
selected = request.POST.getlist(helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)
```

selected is list of string, You should convert to bson.ObjectId.

So  `queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=selected)` will get the right result.

Also you can override the function `def response_action(self, request, queryset):` of admin.Model class to edit the code as this:

```
            selected = request.POST.getlist(helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)
            try:
                from bson import ObjectId
                selected = [ObjectId(item) for item in selected]
            except Exception as e:
                pass
```

[image: code image]